# Jboss AS 7.0 Encrypting Data Source Passwords

Tags: jboss, datasource, password-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt my database password using a JBOSS security domain.

My `standalone.xml` looks like :

```
<datasources>
     <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/integration-ds" pool-name="integration-ds" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
         <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=INTEGRATION_DEV;?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useUnicode=yes</connection-url>
            <driver>sqlserver</driver>
            <security>
            <security-domain>Encrypt</security-domain>
            </security>
      </datasource>
      <drivers>
            <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.test.sqlserver">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
      </drivers>
</datasources>

 <security-domain name="Encrypt"  cache-type="default">
               <authentication>
               <login-module code="SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
               <module-option name="username" value="INTEGRATION_DEV"/>
               <module-option name="password" value="encrypted-password"/>
               </login-module>
               </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

When starting Jboss, I am getting the following error:

> Access Denied:Unauthenticated caller:null: java.lang.SecurityException: PB00024: Access Denied:Unauthenticated caller:null
>   at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.createSubject(JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.java:89)
>       at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer$1.run(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1020)
>       at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer$1.run(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1015)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
>       at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.createSubject(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1014)
>       at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.deployDataSource(AbstractDsDeployer.java:563)
>       at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractDsDeployer.java:283)
>       at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer.deploy(AbstractDataSourceService.java:271)
>       at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService.start(AbstractDataSourceService.java:111)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

On https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1072 , the issue is marked as resolve but fixed versions are not mentioned.
I wanted to know as for which version of Jboss AS the issue is resolved?